# Divider between PreferenceCategory

Tags: android, listview

I know how to change to color of the Headings inside a `PreferenceCategory`.

```
public class PreferenceCategory1 extends PreferenceCategory {
    public PreferenceCategory1(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PreferenceCategory1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PreferenceCategory1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        titleView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(238, 120, 30));

    }
}
```

But I also want to change the Divider between the `PreferenceCategory` and the elements beneath. I've tried to grab the listview and using the setDivider() method:

```
  ListView v = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
  v.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(238, 120, 30)));
```

But this causes a NullPointerException due to the fact that it can't find the `list` in this `view`. I am aware that I can set this in an xml file and add this as a style, but I want, if possible to do this in java. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this: `PreferenceActivity.getListView().setDivider(Drawable divider);`

Comment: Nope doesn't work. the getListView() is not a static method therefor I cant say `myActivity.getListView()`. Cant say `new` either.